# Can I change an image in a WordPress theme?

Tags: wordpress

I have WordPress 3.05 installed on my site and just installed a theme. It looks fine, except for the giant background image at the top, which I'd like to change.

I don't see any settings in the control panel to control images.

Surely I don't have to hack into the PHP code to change an image, right?

Comment: Well, I **did** manage to remove the image by commenting out a line in one of the theme's PHP files, which I found by `grep`-ing for the image name, but I never saw an easier way than that...

Answer (score 1):

If the theme doesn't have it's own admin console piece, then usually you just need to look in it's images directory and find the logo image and replace that image with your own.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

**Replace the image** with your own by going in the theme folder and putting another image in its place. The folder will be located in `wp-content/themes/[theme name]/`. The image can be located right in the root, but most likely it will be in an image folder (or images, or img, ...).

**Change the CSS** by once again going in the theme folder, locating style.css and looking for the string `url(`. There might be more than one instance of the string, just find the right one. Once you do, remove the CSS attribute; it should look like either `background: url([path to image]);` or `background-image: url([path to image]);`, either way delete all from `background` up to the semi-colon.

Comment: It should be noted, that for the first option, you will need FTP access to the site.  The second option could possibly be accomplished by using the Admin -> Theme file editor.